# Excel VBA: Error in file format when saved using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to format the contents of an Excel file, and automatically save it in a specified location with a specified name via a dialog box. I have the codes below, but I am experiencing issues with the file format after I save the file. This is the issue that Excel prompts me:

[image: Error received]

This code allows me to format my excel file to the format I require, and then automatically shows the location and file name that I want to save it in. This codes allows me to save me excel file successfully. However, when I try to open it, it tells me that the file is corrupted, or that the extension is wrong.

Does anyone know why am I experiencing this error? Thanks!

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub externalRatingChangeFile()

'Declare the data type of the variables
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lastCol As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim iRow As Long
Dim sFilename As String
Dim fdlg As FileDialog
Dim xlsxFileFormat As XlFileFormat

'Set wks to the current active worksheet
Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set fdlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'Set the location to save the file to a variable
sFilename = "H:\Testing File\Rating Change - " + Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")
'xlsxFileFormat = XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook

'Within the current active worksheet, identify the last interested row and column of data
'Any values such as 'a', '1' or '%' are considered as values. Spaces (Spacebars) are not considered as values.
With wks
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        lastCol = .Columns.Count
        lastRow = .Rows.Count
    End With

    'Select the interested cells and insert borders around the interested fields
    .UsedRange.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
End With

'Inserting a Row at the top to input Date
Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert

'Input today's Date
wks.Range("A1").Value = "Date: " + Format(Date, "DD MMMM YYYY")

'Save as .xlsx file in the specific location stated earlier

Set fdlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
With fdlg
    .InitialFileName = sFilename
    .Show

'If there are errors in the code, set wks to nothing and end the process
On Error GoTo err_handler
    wks.SaveAs (fdlg.SelectedItems(1))
End With

'System to/not display alerts to notify Users that they are replacing an existing file.
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

err_handler:
'Set wks to its default value
Set wks = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your are starting with a CSV or other non excel format (text file etc...)

If you change the line that actually saves the file to

```
wks.SaveAs (fdlg.SelectedItems(1)) , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

that will force the VBA to save the file in the "correct" format. It would be better to actually pick up the format selected in the dialogue but I dont think it is returned except in the file extension. You could detect that and then choose the matching format but if you are always saving as XLSX then you could just use the above method.

Comment: I believe the file is saved as a text file before I save it again in another location. I managed to solve the problem with your help. Thanks!